# How to hide elements inside function using checkbox?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide in real time all pins on the map.

I can already get `false` or `true` from my checkbox (`var getcheck`) but it doesn't work in real time. When I try to click checkbox, then `setVisible(false)` or `setVisible(true)` won't work.

Also, I don't want to add  `onclick='initMap()'` to the input because then my map will load once again.

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1' id='show_location' checked>
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS

```
function initMap() {

var map;
var markers = [];
var locations = ['<div id="content"> <div id="siteNotice"></div> <h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">dfgdfgdf</h2> <div id="bodyContent"> <p>gdfgdf</p> <p>Location: Detroit, MI, USA</p> <p>Has been there at October 25, 2018, 6:50 pm.</p> </div> </div>', 42.331429, -83.045753, '5'],];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 2,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
});

var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[i % labels.length]
  });
});

var pinBase = '<?=$static_url?>/img/user/pin-';
var pushpinBase = '<?=$static_url?>/img/user/pushpin-';

var num_markers = locations.length;
for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
  markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
    map: map,
    html: locations[i][0],
    id: i,
    icon: pinBase + locations[i][3] + '.png'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      id: this.id,
      content: this.html,
      position: this.getPosition(),
      maxWidth: 340
    });
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function(){
      markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
    });
    this.setVisible(false);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });

  var getcheck = document.getElementById('show_location').checked;

  // here
  alert(getcheck);

  if (getcheck == false) {
    markers[i].setVisible(false);
  } else {
    markers[i].setVisible(true);
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++)` you are fetch all your marker and do something just one time (it's good if you want `.addEventListener()`).

In your case you should put click/change event listener directly to checkbox and hide/show all the marker. Replace the code

```
var getcheck = document.getElementById('show_location').checked;

  // here
  alert(getcheck);

  if (getcheck == false) {
    markers[i].setVisible(false);
  } else {
    markers[i].setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

With this code below

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('check');
toggleMarkers(checkbox);

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

  toggleMarkers(checkbox);

}).bind(checkbox);


let toggleMarkers = (checkbox) => {

  let isChecked = checkbox.checked;
  markers.map((elem) => {
      elem.setVisible(isChecked);
  });
}
```

Comment: I get ERROR `.bind(checkbox);` IS NOT DEFINED and what is `document.getElementById('check');`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant  your document.getElementById('show_location');

Comment: Before I accept your answer. What I need to do if I want to start this from `setVisible(false)`? For example, checkbox is not checked so map should not display locations on map. Now, even If checkbox is not checked, locations are visible.

Comment: That code represented only the change of the status of the checkbox. As a matter of fact you should handle the behaviour at the start as well. You should execute the same code inside the listener twice, before the .addEventListener, too. It would be much clear if I edit the answer.

Comment: I've tested it and work the same like previous code.

Comment: The markers are still visible even if you check/uncheck for n-times? Or the problem is just at the start?

Comment: Works fine if `input` start with `checked` but in opposite action this won't work as I expect. If I check/uncheck n-time, then work, but on first click nothing happen.

Comment: Ok, so you have problem just at the start, and just if at the start the checkbox is UNCHECKED. Ok I will fix it better.

Comment: I think we have got some issues at the start, for some loading technical details. Anyway I supposed you want just to start with all markers not visible, isn't?

Comment: If input is not checked, then start with all not visible markers.

Comment: I don't know what to say, that code supposed to works pretty fine because it check the checkbox value at the start (when it's called in the first time). It's weird you got a wrong behaviour. Try to put "alert(isChecked);"  inside toggleMarkers, just before markers.map(), in order to see if we got the right value in the first place (false if you start with checkbox unchecked) and let me know.

Comment: When input is not checked and I click, then I get `true` in alert.

Comment: Maybe I should add `elem.setVisible(false);` right after `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {`? Because `getcheck.addEventListener('change', (e) => {` will never start from itself because contain `change`. Something like realtimeListener or onLoadListener

Comment: "When input is not checked and I click, then I get true in alert" it's not good, and it's weird. You can get around this weird behavior setting uncheked the checkbox at the start, then at the loading page completed the user will have the markers hidden. You replace the previous alert() with "checkbox.checked = false;". Now you will have all markers hidden at the start. Hope is a good result for you (I don't know why your checkbox is true even when is uncheked).

Comment: Checkbox don't start from true, because map read that locations are visible on start. I've tried to add `checkbox.checked = false;` before `elem.setVisible(isChecked);` and now checkbox doesn't work - locations are not visible on every click and checkbox don't want to check.

Comment: Maybe I supposed to put my hands on the code. Can you share the code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: In this code there are no array markers anymore. You are calling .map( ) with variable marker, but it doesn't exist. By the way there is marker0 and now it works! The problem was the declaration of toggleMarkers( ) supposed to be above the call.

http://jsfiddle.net/xk45jv1a/1/

If you put markers array I can run your code as you asked in the first place, putting .map( ) and toogling with all markers